# sqlplus Input redirection on bash

Tags: linux, bash, sqlplus

New to sqlplus/bash scripting. I currently have a simple script that fetches some value in a table based on some ID values.

```
#do things. get login info. etc....
(cat<<HERE
set heading off;
select data_value from metadata where name='JOHN' and uniqueid in (1, 2, 3);
EOD
) | sqlplus -S $login
#do things.
```

What if instead of having to manually type of the ids (1, 2, 3, etc...), I do this:

```
#calls a script that gets the IDs from somewhere and outputs it in the correct format    
./getIDscript > IDs
#do things. get login info. etc....
(cat<<HERE
set heading off;
select data_value from metadata where name='JOHN' and uniqueid in ($IDs);
EOD
) | sqlplus -S $login
#do things.
```

Would this work? I currently won't have access to the school lab for a few days so I can't test this out right now. 
Is there a better and more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You can use `$(./getIDscript)` in the SQL to insert the result of running `./getIDscript`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 sqlplus -S  /nolog <<_EOD1

 WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
 connect   usr/xxx@db1
 select 1 from dual
 /
 exit
_EOD1
```